# How can I remove the item and its key from localStorage?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I created a simple application that saves and deletes data using [localStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp). The problem is when I delete an item, it deletes only the value not the key so when I load all items those that I deleted come null (of course), I've been searching for a way to delete the key as well, Is there a way to delete it? any help is appreciated.

P.S.: if you can't get the code working here try **[this](http://liveweave.com/ru7yfp)**

**My Code:**

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main">

    <label>Task</label>
    <textarea id="descrip"></textarea>

    <button onclick="saveItUp();" id="save">Save it</button>
    <button onclick="deleteItUp();" id="delete">Delete</button>
  </div>
  <script>
    var taskCounter = Number(localStorage.getItem("count")) + 1;
    var name = taskCounter;
    var deleteTemp = 0;

    for (var i = 1; i < taskCounter; i++) {
      var temp = i;
      document.writeln("<br/>" + '<input type="radio"  name="rad" value="' + temp + '" /> <label>' + 'Code: ' + temp + ' | Value: ' + localStorage.getItem(temp) + '</lable>');
    }

    function saveItUp() {
      var desc = $('#descrip').val();
      alert(desc);
      // Store
      localStorage.setItem(name, desc);
      localStorage.setItem("count", taskCounter);
      // Retrieve
      console.log(localStorage.getItem(name));
      console.log(localStorage.getItem("count"));
      location.reload();
    }

     //This is where I'm trying to do that, I know selected doesn't exist, but I put it just for a better comprehension
    $('input:radio').change(function() {
      if (this.checked) {
        deleteTemp = this.value;
        alert(this.value);
      }
    });

    function deleteItUp() {
      if (deleteTemp !== 0) {
        localStorage.removeItem(deleteTemp);
      } else {
        alert('radio is not checked!');
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [documentation for `localStorage.getItem`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem):

> A DOMString containing the value of the key. **If the key does not exist, null is returned.**

So you **have** removed the item. It's just returning `null` like it would for any other non-existent key.

You can check all the keys that are defined with:

```
var n = 0, key;
while (key = localStorage.key(n++)) console.log(key);
```

You'll see that the key you removed is in fact gone.

Comment: The weird thing is that it keeps the key, if you set a new item the `count` increases if you remove it, it stays the same, unless you delete all the data    AKA `localStorage.clear();`, I think I'll have to check if the key has a value or not, thanks for helping me

Comment: Which `count` are you referring to?

Comment: `localStorage.count`, try running it before adding an item, after adding it, and after deleting it

Comment: I don't see `localStorage.count` in the docs, and in Chrome anyway it returns undefined. Maybe it's an item you defined?

Answer (score 1):

The key-pair are stored as properties of `localStorage`, hence you can just delete the property, which will delete the value too.

```
delete localStorage.count; // deletes both the key and value
```

Comment: @Calne check out my edit. It does delete both key and value

Comment: I tested it, but there's a way to delete only one item, that's the whole point :) ?

Comment: one at a time, using its key to identify it